# Igraph_vector_init_finally and igraph_vector_cumsum

Tags: c, igraph

So I'm looking at the source code of igraph library for c, because I need to create a new type of graph which is not included in that library but it's somehow related to a fitness model graph for free-scale networks. While reading the code relative to the build up of such a graph, I've found that these functions are called in many occasions:

```
(void) IGRAPH_VECTOR_INIT_FINALLY(igraph_vector*,long_int);
(void) igraph_vector_cumsum(igraph_vector*,igraph_vector*);
```

I can't seem to locate it through the folder and I've searched online but it seems that I can't just find what it does. For example, in a portion of the code i have:

```
/* Calculate the cumulative fitness scores */
  IGRAPH_VECTOR_INIT_FINALLY(&cum_fitness_out, no_of_nodes);
  IGRAPH_CHECK(igraph_vector_cumsum(&cum_fitness_out, fitness_out));
  max_out = igraph_vector_tail(&cum_fitness_out);
  p_cum_fitness_out = &cum_fitness_out;
```

where cum_fitness_out it's an empty vector, no_of nodes is the number of nodes, igraph check it's a function to check the return of the function igraph_cumsum, vector tail returns the last element of a vector...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IGRAPH_VECTOR_INIT_FINALLY(vector, size)` is a shorthand for:

```
IGRAPH_CHECK(igraph_vector_init(vector, size));
IGRAPH_FINALLY(igraph_vector_destroy, vector);
```

Basically, it initializes a vector with the given number of undefined elements, checks whether the memory allocation was successful, and then puts the vector on top of the so-called *finally stack* that contains the list of pointers that should be destroyed in case of an error in the code that follows. More information about `IGRAPH_FINALLY` can be found [here](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Error.html#IGRAPH_FINALLY).

`igraph_vector_cumsum()` calculates the cumulative sum of a vector; its source can be found in [`src/vector.pmt`](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/master/src/vector.pmt). `.pmt` stands for "poor man's templates"; it is essentially a C source file with a bunch of macros that allow the library to quickly "generate" the same data type (e.g., vectors) for different base types (integers, doubles, Booleans etc) with some macro trickery.